# Django admin edit only field?

Tags: django, database-design, django-admin

I have a model that I only want to use one row of its table. So, on admin, I would like to remove the list and add pages, and only edit the existing object. The model is this:

```py
from django.db import models


class Banner(models.Model):
    pass

class BannerImg(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="banners")
    banner = models.ForeignKey(Banner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Basically, the Banner(`pk=1`) will be loaded by the frontend to display a landing page hero slider. I want multiple images, but also want them to be on the same admin form, so one could order, add or remove images from the same place. Of course having to `Banner` objects, wouldn't make sense in this case.

I can use `inline` fields to do the form, but how can I achieve the pages functionality (going directly to edit)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Accordion to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

```
from django.contrib import admin

class BannerImgInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BannerImg

class BannerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BannerImgInline,
    ]
```

Comment: I know how to do the form, but I would like to make the field sort of "edit only"

Comment: Mayby you are thinking about [readonly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).